# Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): with grails hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, spring-security

I have integrated spring security plugin with my grails application, which has hibernate as an ORM tool...

using spring security plugin everything is working fine with my application including authentication, authorization...

But recently i got one case where I am facing some issues :

Logged in as : admin
Role to admin : ROLE_ADMIN
ROLE_ADMIN privileges : each and every url is accessible to ROLE_ADMIN

so as an admin user when i am trying to update the privileges assigned to ROLE_ADMIN, its throwing the exception :

```
2011-03-24 10:20:14,035 [http-8080-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
        at ConfigController$_closure45_closure59.doCall(ConfigController:1128)
        at ConfigController$_closure45.doCall(ConfigController:1123)
        at ConfigController$_closure45.doCall(ConfigController)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

May be that's because I am trying the update the privileges of the logged in user itself...

Inside the code also wherever I am saving/updating/deleting any object using hibernate, I m proving flush:false, for e.g. :

```
user.save flush:false
```

So I wanna know that is there any way where logged in user can be able to update the privileges that also going to reflect him/herself too..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [springSecurityService.reauthenticate](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService) after changing the user's role permission. In the 'reauthenticate' section of the linked page is also a good code snippets that should answer your question.